# GWT ValueListBox: can it support more than a single selection?

Tags: gwt, listbox

Can GWT's [ValueListBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html) support multiple selections? Also, is there a way to get it to display more than a single value at a time (like ListBox.setVisibleItemCount()) ?

It seems like you'd need to get at the underlying ListBox (or somehow provide a custom one) in order to make this happen. Of course `getListBox()` is private, so that's out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. ValueListBox is intended to operate on single value. That's why it can be easily used as editor (from Editor framework) for wrapped type.
For multiple selection you can use ListBox, but AFAIK there's no straightforward way to use it as editor (you have to write your own custom editor based on ListBox).